# Dockerized Django app not applying unique constraint

Tags: python, django, postgresql, docker, pgadmin-4

I have two issues both of which are inter-related

**Issue #1**

My app has an online Postgres Database that it is using to store data. Because this  is a Dockerized app, migrations that I create no longer appear on my local host but are instead stored in the Docker container. 
All of the questions I've seen so far do not seem to have issues with making migrations and adding the unique constraint to one of the fields within the table.

I have written shell code to run a python script that returns me the contents of the migrations file in the command prompt window. I was able to obtain the migrations file that was to be applied and added a row to the django_migrations table to specify the same. I then ran makemigrations and migrate but it said there were no changes applied (which leads me to believe that the row which I added into the database should only have automatically been created by django after it had detected migrations on its own instead of me specifying the migrations file and asking it to make the changes). The issue is that now, the new migrations still detect the following change

```
Migrations for 'mdp':
  db4mdp/mdp/migrations/0012_testing.py
    - Alter field mdp_name on languages
```

Despite detecting this apparent 'change', I get the following error,

```
return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
django.db.utils.ProgrammingError: relation "mdp_mdp_mdp_fullname_281e4228_uniq" already exists
```

I have already checked on my postgres server using pgadmin4 to check if the constraint has actually been applied on it. And it has with the name next to relation as specified above. So why then, does Django apparently detect this as a change that is to be made. The thing is, if I now remove the new migrations file that I created in my python directory, it probably will run (since the changes have 'apparently' been made in the database)  but I won't have the migrations file to keep track of the changes. I don't need if I need to keep the migrations around now that I'm using an online database though. I will not be rolling any changes I make back nor will I be making changes to often. This is just a one/two time thing but I want to resolve the error.

**Issue #2**

The reason I used 'apparently' in my above issue is that even though the constraints section in my public schema show me that the constraints have been applied, for some reason, when I try to create a new entry into my table with a non-unique string in the field that I've defined as unique, it allows it creation anyway.

Comment: I'm not quite following your description. Is this Docker env in development or production? If it's prod, you should not be creating migrations there.

Comment: Someone had worked on this project prior to me. Their files were pushed to a github repository which i forked and downloaded and ran with docker. I'm now making modifications to the entire project but the site I'm creating is not currently up and running if that's what you're inquiring

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You never add anything manually to django_migrations table. Let django do it. If it is not doing it, no matter what, you code is not production ready. 
I understand that you are doing your development inside docker. When you do it, you mount your docker volume to local volume. Since you have not mounted that, your migratins will not show in local. 
Refer [Volumes](https://docs.docker.com/storage/volumes/). It should resolve your issues.

Comment: I have removed what I added to the migrations table I realised it was the wrong way to go about things but I know about volume mounting and I don't think that will resolve the issue here. You see django seems to detect me adding the unique=True constraint even though this update has already been made to the field when I access it from pgadmin4 as visible from the second error.

Comment: You can alter models.py to have new db table configurations and re run migration

Comment: That is what I did... read my question I document the process I followed there.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone trying to find an alternate solution to this problem other than mounting volumes due to time constraints, this answer might help but @deosha 's is still the correct way to go about it. I fixed the problem by deleting all my tables and the rows corresponding to migrations to my specific app (it isn't necessary to delete the auth tables etc. because you won't be deleting the rows corresponding to those in the django_migrations table). Following this I used the following within the shell script called by my Dockerfile.

```
python manage.py makemigrations --name testing
python testing_migrations.py
```

It needs to be named for the next step. After this line of code I ran the python script testing_migrations which contains the following code:

```
import os
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))
migrations_file = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, '<path_to_new_migration_file>')
with open(migrations_file, 'r') as file:
    print(file.read())
```

Typically the first migration created for the app you have made will be /0001_testing.py (which is why naming it was necessary earlier). Since the contents of this file are visible to the container while it is up and running, you will be able to print the contents of the file. Then run the migrate command. This creates a column in the django_migrations table that makes it appear to django that the migration has been applied. However, on your local machine this migrations file doesn't exist. So copy the contents of the file from the print statement above and put it into a .py file with the same name as mentioned above and save it in the migrations folder of the above on your local device.

You can follow this method for all successive migrations by repeating the process and incrementing the number in the testing_migrations file as required.

Squashing migrations once you're done making the table will help. If you're doing this all in development and have no requirement to roll-back the changes to the database schema then just put this into production after deleting all the migrations files and the rows in your django_migrations table corresponding to your app as was done initially. Drop your tables and let your first new migrations file re-create them and then import in your data once again.

This is not the recommended method. Use deosha's if you're not on a time crunch.